# Multiple Instance subprocess inputDataItem

Tags: jbpm

I'm trying to use a multiple-instance subprocess (jbpm 7.14.0) with following settings

- **MI Collection input** = data
- **MI Data Input** = item

[image: MI subprocess settings]

If I create MI subprocess via Eclipse I got *id="item"* in *inputDataItem* element, so in subprocess I have variable *item* with current value

```
<bpmn2:inputDataItem xsi:type="bpmn2:tDataInput" id="item" itemSubjectRef="ItemDefinition_610" name="item"/>
```

And if I create subprocess via online editor, then I got *id="_F5E01F15-F1E8-4101-81F9-6F0CAB1A32D2_itemInputX"* and name of the variable with current value is *_F5E01F15-F1E8-4101-81F9-6F0CAB1A32D2_itemInputX*.

```
 <bpmn2:inputDataItem xsi:type="bpmn2:tDataInput" id="_F5E01F15-F1E8-4101-81F9-6F0CAB1A32D2_itemInputX" name="item"/>
```

How to configure the MI subprocess via online editor, to have normal variable name?